# How to restrict users to login in SQL Server by Connect to Server (Additional Connection Parameters Page) option?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I need help to restrict users to login in SQL Server by "additional connection parameters" options.

Can anyone help me? How to control such users by connecting SQL Server by this option?

Comment: I don't understand what your question is here. Are you trying to somehow prevent users from using the additional details?

Comment: Instead of  (Login, pasword) you need to add other parameters?

Comment: actually in my office there's different IT department. i have restricted users by .net sql client  and by name ..etc now i just found the some of users can log in by "(Additional Connection Parameters Page) option by entering some parameters i just wanna restrict that option as well

Comment: You can't. That is shown before the user actually logs in so it would be impossible to know if you should show that or not. My question is, if you have users you want to prevent this for why are they connecting directly with sql server?

Comment: sir as u know its human nature that usually they don't accept restriction so for testing their code directly they used this way to login sql directly.

Comment: i just wanna know is there any way to restrict them as i have applied some triggers for restriction already

Comment: What do you mean by restrict them? It seems you need some help but before that help arrives you need to post a question that is answerable. And why in the world do software testers need to be logging in to the sql server to test code? This is a test database right? So who cares if they screw up the data somewhat?